# Can't Install Java OpenGL Library

Tags: java, jogl

Used [this](https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-1) tutorial I have installed jogl, jocl, gluegen, joal libs and added its to my project but IDE failed to find the following classes

```
...
import javax.media.opengl.DebugGL;
...
import javax.media.opengl.GLCanvas;
import com.sun.opengl.util.FPSAnimator;
import com.sun.opengl.util.GLUT;
...
```

where can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must Install the JOGL Library to run your application, 
you can do it manually here http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/jogl/JOGLInstall.html or
Try this Application, it might help you install JOGL library, but you will need to have administrator access to install it http://cacoinstaller.cyrilinc.co.uk/downloads/

Comment: Your both links are dead, rather look at our official JogAmp wiki: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE